# Div should be hidden but is not

Tags: html, forms, angular

I'm trying to make a login form, but I'm having some trouble with error messages.

I want the 2nd div to be hidden if the form is not submitted, or if the form is submitted AND the password is valid.

The html below is not working:

```
<div class="form-input">
    <input #password type="password" name="password"
    placeholder="Enter Password" required ngModel>

    <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="!form.submitted || (form.submitted && password.valid)">
        Please enter your password.
    </div>
</div>
```

The 2nd div is hidden when the page is first loaded, but if I enter a valid password and press the submit button, it is no longer hidden. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `[]` from `[hidden]` attribute.

Comment: But how to check your password is right or wrong ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using html `input` tag without `FormGroup`. So it does not have a `valid` property. Try to check for `value` instead.

```
[hidden]="!form.submitted || (form.submitted && password.value)"
```

**NOTE**: As suggested by @Jesper `!password.errors.required` will also work.

Or if you want to check for validity, have a function in the component which checks for validity and call in `[hidden]` attribute

In component:

```
isPasswordValid():boolean{
//check this.password validity and return boolean.
}
```

The `[hidden]` attribute:

```
[hidden]="!form.submitted || (form.submitted && isPasswordValid())"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, 'password.value' gets the job done! I just discovered that '!password.errors.required' solves the problem too.